# How to remove a blank array from option input in php

Tags: php

Hi I´m trying to put an array into option input. But the problem is I get one blank option.
I want to remove it.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<select name "x">
$myarray=array('black','blue','brown');
for ($i=0;$i<=count($myarray);$i++){
    if ( $row['colur']==$myarray[$i]) {//if value in database = array$i
        echo"<option value='$myarray[$i]' selected>$myarray[$i]</option>";
    } else {
        echo"<option value='$myarray[$i]'>$myarray[$i]</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional issues with your code (though not answer-worthy): `<select name "x">` -> `<select name="x">`. Judging by the fact that you were able to display options at all, I'm guessing that some spaces/characters were lost in the copy/paste process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507042/if-block-inside-echo-statement to condense your code a bit more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should loop one item less:

```
for ($i=0;$i < count($myarray);$i++) {
```

The last `$i` your loop "sees" is `count($myarray)` which is 3 in your case. However, because arrays are zero-indexed, item `$myarray[3]` doesn't exist (it goes from 0 to 2). The `if` fails and `$myarray[3]` is shown, which doesn't exist: you also get an error of level "notice" in your server logs (which should be the trigger to find this all out yourself).

To prevent all this, use `foreach`:

```
foreach ($myarray as $color) {
    // use $color instead of $myarray[$i]
}
```

Comment: What is the point of do the count every time? this is a bad practice.

Comment: @loops--> Do you have any other ways to suggest me ?

Comment: I would use a foreach instead.

Comment: @PoramatFin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678129/why-count-is-bad-than-count

Comment: How for each is better ? I´ve use both of them but I just aproach with this method as my habbit.

Comment: @PoramatFin it's not a trick, it's a vital part of the language.

Comment: I have one question : for each in javascript is also batter way ? or it´s the same ?

Comment: @PoramatFin `foreach` in Javascript will also give you methods, so I'd say use the `l = arr.Length; for(i =0; i < l; i++) { arr[i]; }` method there.

Answer (score 2):

As array index start from 0 to (array length -1), you should mention your for loop accordingly i.e

```
$array_length = count($myarray);

for ($i=0;$i < $array_length;$i++) {
//your code
}
```